# Flutter widget unresponsive issue

Tags: flutter, widget

In my flutter app, everything is going good but as soon as I try to decrease its size, the container with icons starts showing some yellowish thing, it hides other icons and says like overflowed by 424 pixels. This number increases as much small I make the window.

```
Obx(() =>
         (remoteVideos.isEmpty) ? _buildLoading() : Container()),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    height: 48,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Opacity(
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 48,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: _buildTools(),
```

Comment: Give me full code.
Initially you can try with removing Positioned.

Comment: Can you share code